# Rails -> action method for partial views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, partial

I'm fairly new to rails and want to know how to designate/assign an action method (within a controller) for a partial render.

For example,

I have model A, which is associated with comments (let's call it model B). Model B has a construct for a partial view, which is called from a view within model A -->

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :controller => "comments", :action => "form %>
```

When model A calls this partial render from model B, how can I define a method within model B's controller to be called everytime model A asks for this view? for example, everytime model A calls the partial render, then the "form" method, which is defined within model B controller, will be called. Thanks in advance!!

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def form
        flash[:notice] = "Comment was successfully loaded."
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, it's just a really bad idea.

I think you are a bit confused here. In MVC controllers pass models to views. Models do not (and should not) know that they are passed to a view or rendered in a partial.

Models handle data and business logic, views present it to the user and controllers handle responding to user input and passing it to models.

In Rails each request is handled by a single controller. In your case you would want to do something like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    flash[:notice] = "Comments loaded." if @comments.any?
    render :show
  end
end
```

If you want to reuse code in between controllers you can use [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Comment: appreciate the background and the answer, very helpful.